# BroadcastReceiver para monitorear si el WIFI esta conectado o desconectado

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Estoy usando este **BroadcastReceiver para monitorear si el WIFI esta conectado o desconectado**, pero no me esta funcionando, detecta que el WIFI esta conectado pero no cuando se desconecta, alguien me puede decir cual es el error?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private BroadcastReceiver WifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int WifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,
                WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);

        switch (WifiState) {
            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED: {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Wifi enabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;

            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING: {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Wifi enabling",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED: {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Wifi disabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;

            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING: {
            }
            break;

            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN: {
            }
            break;
        }
    } };

protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(WifiReceiver, new IntentFilter( WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
}

protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(WifiReceiver);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes obtener cuando no existe conexión mediante :

> [ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY):  indica si hay una
>   falta completa de conectividad, es decir, no hay red disponible.

```
if(intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, Boolean.FALSE)) {
      Log.i("Network", "No existe conectividad!");
}
```

De acuerdo a lo anterior esta es una clase de ejemplo:

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
     if(intent.getExtras() != null) {
        NetworkInfo ni = (NetworkInfo) intent.getExtras().get(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if(ni != null && ni.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
             Toast.makeText(context,"Wifi enabled " + ni.getTypeName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if(intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, Boolean.FALSE)) {
             Toast.makeText(context,"Wifi disabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
   }
}
```

No olvides registrar tu `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
<receiver android:name=". WifiReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```